# Recover long from int after precision loss

Tags: algorithm, casting, int, type-conversion, long-integer

I inherited an application that took `2281534395476` and incorrectly casted it to an integer of `906761300`. I'm looking to essentially un-cast it back to its proper and correct `(long)` data type.

What is a reproducible algorithm for doing so that could be run over a list? I'm looking for pseudocode or something of the sort, although the end result will be written in Ruby.

Comment: That's obviously impossible, those bits are just gone. Or can you infer them from other information or domain knowledge somehow?

Comment: ... you want to recover `long` from `int`? is that what you are looking for? if it's so, unfortunately, the answer is no, the solution is to change every occurrence of that variable to `long`.

Comment: @harold as the first responder, please add an answer so I can mark it

Comment: You can mark that one. I was really hoping that some interesting things could be done with some knowledge about what that numbers represent, this way I can't really write anything interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simply cannot get the value back when already casted from `long` to `int`. When you are casting from `long` to `int`, you are losing some bits. So, you just can't get back those bits and can't get back your lost `long` value by using a generic algorithm.

In a system , where `long` and `int` uses same number of bits, the conversion is trivial; it simply copies the value. In this case, you may get the value back.

On a system where `long` is wider than `int`, if the `long` value won't fit in an `int`, then the result of the conversion is implementation-defined. What typically happens is that the high-order bits are discarded. Your system seems to be this one. So, you can't get back the `long` value.

Comment: Actually **"Does not"** does not imply **"can not"**. So, I modified that. :)